# Issue installing numpy on an onprem server through putty

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, numpy, installation, pip

I'm new to this stuff and I got a really long message.

Collecting numpy==1.16.6

Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b7/6f/24647f014eef9b67a24adfcbcd4f4928349b4a0f8393b3d7fe648d4d2de3/numpy-1.16.6.zip

Installing collected packages: numpy

Running setup.py install for numpy ... error

```
Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-4ZMnC0/numpy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__)().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-dRJlZG/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compilrefix=:

Running from numpy source directory.



Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install

with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:



  - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source

                           release)

  - `pip install numpy`   (last NumPy release on PyPi)





blas_opt_info:

blas_mkl_info:

customize UnixCCompiler

C compiler: cc -DNDEBUG -KPIC -DPIC



creating /tmp/tmpqQnW4y/tmp

creating /tmp/tmpqQnW4y/tmp/tmpqQnW4y

compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpqQnW4y/file.c.d -c'

cc: /tmp/tmpqQnW4y/file.c

  libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/lib']

  NOT AVAILABLE



blis_info:

customize UnixCCompiler

C compiler: cc -DNDEBUG -KPIC -DPIC



creating /tmp/tmpcuERKU/tmp

creating /tmp/tmpcuERKU/tmp/tmpcuERKU

compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpcuERKU/file.c.d -c'

cc: /tmp/tmpcuERKU/file.c

  libraries blis not found in ['/usr/lib']

  NOT AVAILABLE



openblas_info:

customize UnixCCompiler

C compiler: cc -DNDEBUG -KPIC -DPIC



creating /tmp/tmp2IvNik/tmp

creating /tmp/tmp2IvNik/tmp/tmp2IvNik

compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmp2IvNik/file.c.d -c'

cc: /tmp/tmp2IvNik/file.c

customize UnixCCompiler

C compiler: cc -DNDEBUG -KPIC -DPIC



creating /tmp/tmpIp91Qu/tmp

creating /tmp/tmpIp91Qu/tmp/tmpIp91Qu

compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpIp91Qu/file.c.d -c'

cc: /tmp/tmpIp91Qu/file.c

  libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/lib']

  NOT AVAILABLE



atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:

Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS

customize UnixCCompiler

C compiler: cc -DNDEBUG -KPIC -DPIC



creating /tmp/tmpZNdvgg/tmp

creating /tmp/tmpZNdvgg/tmp/tmpZNdvgg

compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpZNdvgg/file.c.d -c'

cc: /tmp/tmpZNdvgg/file.c

  libraries tatlas not found in ['/usr/lib']

  NOT AVAILABLE



atlas_3_10_blas_info:

customize UnixCCompiler

C compiler: cc -DNDEBUG -KPIC -DPIC



creating /tmp/tmpa_ZIhU/tmp

creating /tmp/tmpa_ZIhU/tmp/tmpa_ZIhU

compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpa_ZIhU/file.c.d -c'

cc: /tmp/tmpa_ZIhU/file.c

  libraries satlas not found in ['/usr/lib']

  NOT AVAILABLE



atlas_blas_threads_info:

Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS

customize UnixCCompiler

C compiler: cc -DNDEBUG -KPIC -DPIC



creating /tmp/tmpim5bAl/tmp

creating /tmp/tmpim5bAl/tmp/tmpim5bAl

compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpim5bAl/file.c.d -c'

cc: /tmp/tmpim5bAl/file.c

  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/lib']

  NOT AVAILABLE



atlas_blas_info:

customize UnixCCompiler

C compiler: cc -DNDEBUG -KPIC -DPIC



creating /tmp/tmpSrYFHQ/tmp

creating /tmp/tmpSrYFHQ/tmp/tmpSrYFHQ

compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpSrYFHQ/file.c.d -c'

cc: /tmp/tmpSrYFHQ/file.c

  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/lib']

  NOT AVAILABLE



accelerate_info:

  NOT AVAILABLE



/tmp/pip-install-4ZMnC0/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:639: UserWarning:

    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting

    the ATLAS environment variable.

  self.calc_info()

blas_info:

customize UnixCCompiler

C compiler: cc -DNDEBUG -KPIC -DPIC



creating /tmp/tmpn8ueKo/tmp

creating /tmp/tmpn8ueKo/tmp/tmpn8ueKo

compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpn8ueKo/file.c.d -c'

cc: /tmp/tmpn8ueKo/file.c

  libraries blas not found in ['/usr/lib']

  NOT AVAILABLE



/tmp/pip-install-4ZMnC0/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:639: UserWarning:

    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting

    the BLAS environment variable.

  self.calc_info()

blas_src_info:

  NOT AVAILABLE



/tmp/pip-install-4ZMnC0/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:639: UserWarning:

    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.

    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting

    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.

  self.calc_info()

  NOT AVAILABLE



/bin/sh: svnversion: not found

non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'

lapack_opt_info:

lapack_mkl_info:

customize UnixCCompiler

C compiler: cc -DNDEBUG -KPIC -DPIC



creating /tmp/tmpZMQg1A/tmp

creating /tmp/tmpZMQg1A/tmp/tmpZMQg1A

compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpZMQg1A/file.c.d -c'

cc: /tmp/tmpZMQg1A/file.c

  libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/lib']

  NOT AVAILABLE



openblas_lapack_info:

customize UnixCCompiler

C compiler: cc -DNDEBUG -KPIC -DPIC



creating /tmp/tmpQu2cHV/tmp

creating /tmp/tmpQu2cHV/tmp/tmpQu2cHV

compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpQu2cHV/file.c.d -c'

cc: /tmp/tmpQu2cHV/file.c

customize UnixCCompiler

C compiler: cc -DNDEBUG -KPIC -DPIC



creating /tmp/tmpxIoiiU/tmp

creating /tmp/tmpxIoiiU/tmp/tmpxIoiiU

compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpxIoiiU/file.c.d -c'

cc: /tmp/tmpxIoiiU/file.c

  libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/lib']

  NOT AVAILABLE



openblas_clapack_info:

customize UnixCCompiler

C compiler: cc -DNDEBUG -KPIC -DPIC



creating /tmp/tmpViIFo1/tmp

creating /tmp/tmpViIFo1/tmp/tmpViIFo1

compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpViIFo1/file.c.d -c'

cc: /tmp/tmpViIFo1/file.c

customize UnixCCompiler

C compiler: cc -DNDEBUG -KPIC -DPIC



creating /tmp/tmpdQVB5_/tmp

creating /tmp/tmpdQVB5_/tmp/tmpdQVB5_

compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpdQVB5_/file.c.d -c'

cc: /tmp/tmpdQVB5_/file.c

  libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/usr/lib']

  NOT AVAILABLE



atlas_3_10_threads_info:

Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS

customize UnixCCompiler

C compiler: cc -DNDEBUG -KPIC -DPIC



creating /tmp/tmpDM2zdM/tmp

creating /tmp/tmpDM2zdM/tmp/tmpDM2zdM

compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpDM2zdM/file.c.d -c'

cc: /tmp/tmpDM2zdM/file.c

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib

customize UnixCCompiler

C compiler: cc -DNDEBUG -KPIC -DPIC



creating /tmp/tmpAjVPmw/tmp

creating /tmp/tmpAjVPmw/tmp/tmpAjVPmw

compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpAjVPmw/file.c.d -c'

cc: /tmp/tmpAjVPmw/file.c

 libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib

<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>

  NOT AVAILABLE



atlas_3_10_info:

customize UnixCCompiler

C compiler: cc -DNDEBUG -KPIC -DPIC



creating /tmp/tmprfvjYs/tmp

creating /tmp/tmprfvjYs/tmp/tmprfvjYs

compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmprfvjYs/file.c.d -c'

cc: /tmp/tmprfvjYs/file.c

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib

customize UnixCCompiler

C compiler: cc -DNDEBUG -KPIC -DPIC



creating /tmp/tmpYQqAE_/tmp

creating /tmp/tmpYQqAE_/tmp/tmpYQqAE_

compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpYQqAE_/file.c.d -c'

cc: /tmp/tmpYQqAE_/file.c

  libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib

<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>

  NOT AVAILABLE



atlas_threads_info:

Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS

customize UnixCCompiler

C compiler: cc -DNDEBUG -KPIC -DPIC



creating /tmp/tmpxvYLYz/tmp

creating /tmp/tmpxvYLYz/tmp/tmpxvYLYz

compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpxvYLYz/file.c.d -c'

cc: /tmp/tmpxvYLYz/file.c

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib

customize UnixCCompiler

C compiler: cc -DNDEBUG -KPIC -DPIC



creating /tmp/tmpG0bI6R/tmp

creating /tmp/tmpG0bI6R/tmp/tmpG0bI6R

compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpG0bI6R/file.c.d -c'

cc: /tmp/tmpG0bI6R/file.c

  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib

<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>

  NOT AVAILABLE



atlas_info:

customize UnixCCompiler

C compiler: cc -DNDEBUG -KPIC -DPIC



creating /tmp/tmp4vKZ_0/tmp

creating /tmp/tmp4vKZ_0/tmp/tmp4vKZ_0

compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmp4vKZ_0/file.c.d -c'

cc: /tmp/tmp4vKZ_0/file.c

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib

customize UnixCCompiler

C compiler: cc -DNDEBUG -KPIC -DPIC



creating /tmp/tmpjnvkF7/tmp

creating /tmp/tmpjnvkF7/tmp/tmpjnvkF7

compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpjnvkF7/file.c.d -c'

cc: /tmp/tmpjnvkF7/file.c

  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib

<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>

  NOT AVAILABLE



lapack_info:

customize UnixCCompiler

C compiler: cc -DNDEBUG -KPIC -DPIC



creating /tmp/tmpwppskV/tmp

creating /tmp/tmpwppskV/tmp/tmpwppskV

compile options: '-MMD -MF /tmp/tmpwppskV/file.c.d -c'

cc: /tmp/tmpwppskV/file.c

  libraries lapack not found in ['/usr/lib']

  NOT AVAILABLE
```

/tmp/pip-install-4ZMnC0/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:639: UserWarning:

```
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting

    the LAPACK environment variable.

  self.calc_info()

lapack_src_info:

  NOT AVAILABLE



/tmp/pip-install-4ZMnC0/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:639: UserWarning:

    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.

    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting

    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.

  self.calc_info()

  NOT AVAILABLE



/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'

  warnings.warn(msg)

running install

running build

running config_cc

unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options

running config_fc

unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options

running build_src

build_src

building py_modules sources

creating build

creating build/src.solaris-2.11-sun4v.32bit-2.7

creating build/src.solaris-2.11-sun4v.32bit-2.7/numpy

creating build/src.solaris-2.11-sun4v.32bit-2.7/numpy/distutils

building library "npymath" sources

get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['sun', 'gnu', 'gnu95', 'g95']'

customize SunFCompiler

Could not locate executable f90

customize GnuFCompiler

Could not locate executable g77

Could not locate executable f77

customize Gnu95FCompiler

Could not locate executable gfortran

Could not locate executable f95

customize G95FCompiler

Could not locate executable g95

don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'

C compiler: cc -DNDEBUG -KPIC -DPIC



compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort de/python2.7 -c'

cc: _configtest.c

failure.

removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip-install-4ZMnC0/numpy/setup.py", line 419, in <module>

    setup_package()

  File "/tmp/pip-install-4ZMnC0/numpy/setup.py", line 411, in setup_package

   setup(**metadata)

  File "/tmp/pip-install-4ZMnC0/numpy/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 171, in setup

    return old_setup(**new_attr)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/vendor-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 129, in setup

    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup

    dist.run_commands()

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands

    self.run_command(cmd)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "/tmp/pip-install-4ZMnC0/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/install.py", line 62, in run

    r = self.setuptools_run()

  File "/tmp/pip-install-4ZMnC0/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/install.py", line 36, in setuptools_run

    return distutils_install.run(self)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 563, in run

    self.run_command('build')

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command

    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "/tmp/pip-install-4ZMnC0/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build.py", line 47, in run

    old_build.run(self)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 127, in run

    self.run_command(cmd_name)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command

    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "/tmp/pip-install-4ZMnC0/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 148, in run

    self.build_sources()

  File "/tmp/pip-install-4ZMnC0/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 159, in build_sources

    self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)

  File "/tmp/pip-install-4ZMnC0/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 292, in build_library_sources

    sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))

  File "/tmp/pip-install-4ZMnC0/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 375, in generate_sources

    source = func(extension, build_dir)

  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 667, in get_mathlib_info

    raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")

RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program



----------------------------------------
```

Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-install-4ZMnC0/numpy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace(';f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-dRJlZG/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failr code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-4ZMnC0/numpy/

Comment: Hi there, so many questions... what line/file/command caused this error? was it the one listed at the very bottom? Have you tried to understand your code yourself(which it doesn't seem you've posted)? And what have you tried to do to fix it?

Comment: Hi, I tried to install numpy using the pip install command . The server is a Solaris server. The error was with setup.py. but I'm not sure what's exactly causing the error. I have posted whole error message because I didn't understand the error even after trying to read it.